the pointwise limit of a sequence of convex, continuous function is lower semi-continuous
Suppose we have a sequence of convex, continuous functions $\{f_n(x)\}$, and its pointwise limit function is denoted by $f(x)$. I am considering if $f$ is always lower semi-continuous.
If $f_n$ is not restricted to convex, then the statement is false. However, if they are convex, I did not find any counter-example. Is there any counter-example or can the statement be proved true?

what kind of domain are you interested in? $\mathbb R^n$, convex subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ or Banach spaces in general?

Let $f_n:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ be the continuous, convex, piecewise linear function whose graph is the polygonal path connecting the points $(0,1), (1/n,0), (1-1/n,0), (1,1)$.  For each $x\in[0,1]$ we have $\lim_n f_n(x)=f(x)$, where $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ is the convex function
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases} 1 & x=0\\0 & 0<x<1 \\ 1&x=1.\end{cases}
$$
The limit function is upper semicontinuous but not lower semi semicontinuous.
Or, simpler, the convex functions $f_n(x)=x^n$ converges pointwise on $[0,1]$ to a non lsc function.
